# Why do I need to define an index route in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

Previously, my routes were defined:

```
this.route('username', {
  path: '/:username'
}, function() {
  this.route("room", {
    path: "/:room",
});
```

I changed it to:

```
this.route('username', {
    path: '/:username'
  }, function() {
    this.route('index')
});
this.route("room", {
  path: "/:room"
});
```

This works fine. But my `username/index` route will not load unless I explicitly define index in `router.js`.

The following will **not** work:

```
this.route('username', {
  path: '/:username'
});
this.route("room", {
  path: "/:room",
});
```

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Maybe you can show an example like this: https://ember-twiddle.com/c310013f69c086cecaa38b1d355c49f3?openFiles=templates.username.hbs%2C&route=%2Fusername  I usually don't use the index routes and instead name them more specifically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a `route` has nested `route`s, it is assumed that there is an `index` route for the parent.  This refers to this in the guide: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_index-routes

In particular, the key phrase is:

> At every level of nesting (including the top level), Ember automatically provides a route for the / path named index. To see when a new level of nesting occurs, check the router, whenever you see a function, that's a new level.

So, in your example, because `room` is nested within `username`, then `username` gets an automatic `index` route.  When you removed `room` from the nesting, then the default `index` route for `username` went away.

FYI, you don't even have to specify the index route, just supply an empty callback.  e.g.:

```
this.route('username', {
    path: '/:username'
  }, function() {});
```

This will work the same way by automatically creating the `username/index` route.

In one of my early Ember apps (1.x), I wanted the index route to always be there, regardless (for consistency), so I defined a variable:

```
var NO_CHILDREN= function() {};
```

Then I could write my routes like:

```
this.route('username', {
    path: '/:username'
  }, NO_CHILDREN);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: That's very interesting, and not what I would have expected. Thank you, this answer has broadened my understanding (and hopefully that of others in the future)!